# How to import gitlab repository to bitbucket Repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitlab

I have a gitlab Repository and I want it to update it on the bitbucket account.

> Please provide me steps to follow, so that it can be helpful to me to
>   migrate it in bitbucket from Gitlab.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? It's always possible to add an additional remote to a local clone and push to it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Create a new repo in bitbucket.
2. `git clone <gitlabRepoUrl>`
3. `cd <repoName>`
4. `git remote add bitbucket <bitbucketRepoUrl>`
5. `git push bitbucket master`

Comment: Bishakh Ghosh :
Thanks first. 
Do I have to commit each branch one by one? As when I did this only master is setup in the bitbucket. Please guide how to import all branches at once.

Comment: You can use `git push --all bitbucket` to push all branches.

Answer (score 44):

1) Create the repository in Bitbucket using the UI

2) Clone the Gitlab repository using the "--bare" option

```
git clone --bare GITLAB-URL
```

3) Add the Bitbucket remote

```
cd REPO-NAME
git remote add bitbucket BITBUCKET-URL
```

4) Push all commits, branches and tags to Bitbucket

```
git push --all bitbucket
git push --tags bitbucket
```

5) Remove the temp repository

```
cd ..
rm -rf REPO-NAME
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. it was helpful.

Comment: Is there a way to make this recursive to include subrepos? 
What I see in bitbucket now is "Name of subrepo" → git@domain.com/path/to/subrepo.git

Comment: perfect because I needed to import all my commits too and now all are fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it straight from the repositories themselves there is a way also.

1. Rsync the /home/git/repositories directory (copying them is less risky than working on source files themselves) to your home dir

   `sudo rsync -avzh /home/git/repositories /home/<YOURUSER>/repos/`
2. Set the permissions on your repos dir to yourself

   `sudo chown -R <YOURUSER>:<YOURUSER> /home/<YOURUSER>/repos`
3. Create the empty repo on bitbucket.
4. Mirror them locally to create a working copy that contains all branches and tags with you.

   `git clone --mirror git@gitlab.mydomain.com/source-repo.git`
5. Then you would want to simply push the mirror.

   `cd source-repo.git`
   `git push --mirror git@bitbucket.com/new-location.git`

Answer (score 0):

You must bear in mind that you must have a local copy of all remote branches and from that run

```
git push --all new-repository
git push --tags new-repository
```

Here is a try on how you can have local copies of all remote branches

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(git branch -r | grep -vE "HEAD|master"); do 
    git branch --track ${i#*/} $i; done
git push --all bitbucket
git push --tags bitbucket
```

Comment: Hi! This is an answer to an old question, moreover it does not seem to address the topic... Could you explain why you wrote it?

Comment: because they have not indicated how to import the repository without losing the branches